# android Single service for multiple tasks

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

How do i do multiple background tasks in Android?
i have three checkboxes in my activity. images,audio and videos. so I have 3 long background task (independent to each other) to do. So, I wrote a service class for uploading images.My question is, for the 2nd  and 3rd tasks which is uploading videos and audio, should I make two more service classes? what would be the best way to perform these three tasks if user check three boxes at a time ?

And my second question is i have seen somewhere that someone is using  async task inside service for long background  processing. I was wondered if you are using service then why is the need of async task? is this a better way to use asynctask inside a service for such tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A service **runs on the main thread**. It's a huge mistake thinking that the service runs on a different thread. That's why you need an AsyncTask() or a Runnable() or a Thread().

So if you already decided to create a service, then the best thing to do would create 1, 2, or 3 threads inside the service.

But ask yourself why you're using a service in the first place? A service is intended to work even if the applications is not in the foreground. So maybe you don't need the service at all, you can create the background threads in the activity itself.

Comment: well yeah i need a service because i want to keep backup images or videos everytime. so can i use three services for these three tasks ?is that a better approach ? or create three threads inside a service ?

Comment: I would definitely use one single service with 3 threads. It's much easier to encapsulate the logic of 3 threads inside a service, than having 3 services.

Answer (score 0):

A Service is designed for long running background tasks. The use-case of a Service is to run while the App is in the background. Or while you are switching between Activities, the Task will not be killed.

But it runs in the UI-Thread like an Activity. That's why you have to use a Thread or AsyncTask to not block the UI-Thread. It's fine if you have some independent Threads/AsyncTasks for different jobs in one Service. In your case, every Checkbox can run a different Thread in this Service.

Comment: well before service i was using asynctask for uploading. but then my apps become slow ,sometimes checkbox freezes and sometimes gives me force close message

Comment: In this case add some relevant code to your question that we can see what is going on.